# Matplotlib plotting dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to learn how to plot dataframes. I read in a csv and have the following columns:

```
 cost, model, origin, year
--------------------------
200    x1     usa     2020
145    x1     chn     2020
233    x1     usa     2020
122    x2     chn     2020
583    x2     usa     2020
233    x3     chn     2020 
201    x3     chn     2020
```

I'm trying to create a bar plot and only want to plot the average cost per model.

Here's my attempt, but I dont think im on the right track:

```
df = df.groupby('cost').mean()
plt.bar(df.index, df['model'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data frame?

Comment: @RithwikBabu let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` model, then calculate the `mean` of cost and `plot` it:

```
df.groupby('model')['cost'].mean().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image: picture]

---

Or with `seaborn`:

```
sns.barplot(data=df, x='model', y='cost', ci=None)
```

Output:

[image: picture]

Comment: thank you for providing this. So question ontop of this. Lets say theres 100+ models. If i wanted to take the head(20) and sort in descending order. How would i do that?

Comment: Sort in descending order by average cost or by the name of the model?

Comment: sorry for not specifying. sorting in descending order by average cost!

Comment: Sure, you just add `.nlargest(20)`, making it `df.groupby('model')['cost'].mean().nlargest(20).plot.bar()`

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas plot function like so:

```
df.plot.bar(x='model', y='cost')
```

Comment: im struggling with plotting the "the average cost per model". How would i get the average/mean?

Comment: `df.groupby('model')['cost'].mean()`